# jQuery click event doesn't work independantly

Tags: jquery, click

I got problem with jQuery code. Here is the code:

[code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/25ZWF/2/)

Problem parts are with:

```
$(document).unbind('click').on('click', '#a_del', function() {
    $('.a_frm > .frmlabel:last').remove();
    a_counter--;
    $('#a_field_count').attr('value', a_counter);
  });

$(document).unbind('click').on('click', '#b_del', function() {
    $('.b_frm > .frmlabel:last').remove();
    b_counter--;
    $('#b_field_count').attr('value', b_counter);
  });
```

Problem is that remove button doesn't work for both forms. If I add only one of that remove button code then it deletes correctly form fields. But when I add code for second form remove buttons then works only latest form remove buttons and first form buttons doesn't work anymore.. I can't understand what's the problem. 
Thank you!

Comment: You should use `off` instead of `unbind` when you bind an event with `on`. (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use off and namespace:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25ZWF/4/)

```
$(document).off('click.a').on('click.a', '#a_del', function() {
    $('.a_frm > .frmlabel:last').remove();
    a_counter--;
    $('#a_field_count').attr('value', a_counter);
  });

$(document).off('click.b').on('click.b', '#b_del', function() {
    $('.b_frm > .frmlabel:last').remove();
    b_counter--;
    $('#b_field_count').attr('value', b_counter);
  });
```

But as you are using delegation, i don't know why you want to unbind it?!